# WordPress plugin to let client manage content of editable elements

Tags: web-development, cms, web, wordpress, web-services

I need a WordPress plugin to let the client can manage the content of editable elements:

- Create custom HTML Elements. Code classes in one `.css` file, so client could add new element and add my custom class to it.
- Create completely custom navbar and footer (I don'require them to be editable), also single-pages.
- Add `.js` file to every web-page automatically.

This all needs to be possibe:

- with a Wordpress plugin
- via drag-and-drop

Which software would enable me to do that? I've read about Elementor FREE, but I don't know if it covers this – so I'm open to other suggestions as well.